# What does “…but the ones who are commit nearly half of the most serious crimes“ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following passage is from a book called the righteous mind by the moral psychologist Jonanthan Haidt.

> Roughly one in a hundred men (and many fewer women) are psychopaths. Most are not violent, **but the ones who are commit nearly half of the most serious crimes**, such as serial murder, serial rape, and the killing of police officers.

I feel that the meaning is not complete, specifically, what does he mean by:

> Most are not violent, but the ones who are commit nearly half of the most serious crimes, such as serial murder, serial rape, and the killing of police officers.

More specifically, what does the following  sentence mean?

> …but the ones who are commit nearly half of the most serious crimes…

Please, I want a rewording of the entire passage to get the exact meaning.

Comment: I can answer it. But before that I would ask you to try. One thing I can say is that this is correct. There is no error. And the "the ones" after "but" is getting post modified by a relative clause, which again contains a missing word (that is correct). Now can you try to figure out?

Answer (score 2):

One in one hundred men are psychopaths. Most of those who are psychopaths *are not* violent, but those psychopaths who *are* violent commit nearly half of all serious crimes.

*The ones who are* means the fraction of psychopaths who are violent. The word "violent" has been elided from this subordinate clause.

So, 1% of men are psychopaths.
Some, but not all, men who are psychopaths are violent.
That group (psychopaths who are violent) are responsible for 1/2 of violent crimes.

The size of the fraction of psychopaths who are violent is not specified in the passage,.